# Products in TWIG horizontal

Tags: symfony

I am having a very difficult time with Symfony to print the products(not a form) from left to right and not in a vertical list. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this a Symfony or a CSS question?

Comment: I need to get a symfony twig to print the products from left to right. So I think it should be symfony?

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: @Colin Well, not really. Symfony (and PHP for that matter) usually manage the backend, that means keeping track of what is a product, etc. Displaying it (from left to right, top to bottom, all in glitter and with animations) is a HTML & CSS job, no matter the backend

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really Symfony-related, as Symfony provides the data you pass to a Twig view, which displays retrieved data.

For your question you could use a *ul* and modify it to display it's list items horizontally:

CSS

```
#test li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="test">
    <li>Product 1</li>
    <li>Product 2</li>
    <li>Product 3</li>
</ul>
```